Jolt Transformer to match key array with value arrays
I have a json input object, and want to do a json transformation using jolt transformer. can help to acheive this
Input is
{
  "keys": [
    "key1",
    "key2",
    "key3"
  ],
  "values": [
    [
      "value 1.1",
      "value 2.1",
      "value 3.1"
    ],
    [
      "value 1.2",
      "value 2.2",
      "value 3.2"
    ]
  ]
}

and the expected output is
{
  "Result": [
    {
      "key1": "value 1.1",
      "key2": "value 2.1",
      "key3": "value 3.1"
    },
    {
      "key1": "value 1.2",
      "key2": "value 2.2",
      "key3": "value 3.2"
    }
  ]
}


You can loop hrough values array while picking the values from the keys after traversing 3 levels such that
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "values": {
        "*": {
          "*": "Result[&1].@(3,keys[&])"// &1 represents the outer indexes under "values" node 
                                        // &  is for the inner indexes
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

